# Thunderbird says my inbox is 80% full; ISP says no limit. What gives?

Tags: email, thunderbird

Thunderbird has been reporting that I'm using 81% of my inbox quota, but my ISP says I have no inbox quota. One of them is wrong. How do I go about figuring out who?

Comment: This has to be one of the funniest questions I've seen in a while :) - Thunderbird can tell you your quota?

Comment: @Roland yes, Thunderbird can tell you your email quota.

Comment: @Roland, yup. By default it only shows up when  you're over 75% but you can change the threshold by tweaking `mail.quota.mainwindow_threshold.show`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unlikely that your ISP really has given you an unlimited inbox. Perhaps they've assigned a certain size and will increase it as needed if you use up what they give. If your inbox starts taking up several gigabytes or so, I'd expect for your ISP to talk to you about your usage.

Comment: Is there a way to look for myself? How is this information being reported to Thunderbird?

Comment: Realized I did want to know that, so http://askubuntu.com/questions/39674/can-i-speak-imap-and-review-my-actual-mail-quota