# Can I "speak IMAP" and review my actual mail quota?

Tags: command-line, email, thunderbird

I'm trying to troubleshoot a frustrating inbox quota issue. [Thunderbird says my inbox is 80% full.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38238/thunderbird-says-my-inbox-is-80-full-isp-says-no-limit-what-gives/38320#38320) My ISP says it isn't. We made some tweaks and I should have 2G available (it had been "unlimited"). Thunderbird, unfortunately, still reports that I'm using 206456 of my 256000 KB limit on Quota Root "ROOT."

Is there a command line method I can use to find out what my mail host is telling Thunderbird? Can Mutt tell me?

Comment: Sniffing around here: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2087.html

Comment: You have 2G of space, but the root storage is limited to 256M? I saw the same error and tried to reduce my inbox which didn't help. However, when I created another folder under Archive and moved most of my mail from the default archive folder to the new folder, it resolved the problem (though I had to take down thunderbird and restart to force thunderbird to re-check the quota.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps the Python `imaplib` library could help.  Launch a python console from the terminal with `python`. Then, create an IMAP connection with the following commands:

```
>>> import imaplib
>>> conn = imaplib.IMAP4('hostname')
>>> conn.login('username', 'password')
```

If your IMAP server uses SSL, use the `IMAP4_SSL` constructor instead of `IMAP4`.  You can then use the `getquotaroot` or `getquota` methods on the connection.  For example:

```
>>> conn.getquotaroot('INBOX')
>>> conn.getquota('quota root') # using the root from the previous command
```

Comment: Bingo. `('OK', [['"INBOX" "ROOT"'], ['"ROOT" (STORAGE 206431 256000)']])` ... so Thunderbird is not wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Using `openssl` :

```
openssl s_client -connect example.org:imap -starttls imap
```

then log in when you get a prompt :

```
a LOGIN user@example.org password
```

and finally :

```
a GETQUOTA ""
```